# How can I recover private key as coins were sent a random generated address on wallet?

Tags: address-generation, recover-private-key, ios

There is a new address where the coins reside and asks for a private key.

How can I send coins from this  new random address without knowing the private key?

Software: http://www.sollico.com/bitwallet/

Answer (score 1):

If the address is not part of any of the wallets that you have control over than you cannot recover the private keys. Because in that case, you're basically asking the same as asking to recover the private key to anybody's bitcoin address. I'm sure you know the answer to that question.

If the address is part of one of the addresses of **your** wallet at bitWallet, you can just spend from your wallet as usual. If you meant to ask how to do that, please update your question to reflect that.

Comment: The address is part of my wallet but it requiring a private key to send the transactions. I never had to enter my key when I created the wallet to send coins but the last transactions generated a new address and transferred the coins in there leaving a blank private key.

Comment: Contact their support email address. Make sure to include enough details, but not things like your password. support@sollico.com